# Customizing a specific type interferes with population of shared base property in other types

Tags: autofixture

I'm trying to use AutoFixture to ease the population of data entities in my automated tests. Entities have a base id and several methods for determining equality and whether an object has been persisted or not. Some of the entities need specific values, so I tried to customize them but then started having errors trying to save other entities because the base id was not getting populated.

Here is a simplification; the third test fails and illustrates the problem. Am I misunderstanding how Customize works, or is this a bug in AutoFixture? I'm using version 3.40.

```
[TestFixture]
public class AutoFixtureTestsWithWorkaround
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContractType : Entity
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_populate_ContractType_with_customization_using_specimen_context()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.Customize<ContractType>(composer => composer
            .With(x => x.Id, "FM")
            .With(x => x.Description, "Full Maintenance")
            );

        var specimenContext = new SpecimenContext(fixture);
        var ct = (ContractType)specimenContext.Resolve(typeof(ContractType));

        Assert.AreEqual("FM", ct.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual("Full Maintenance", ct.Description);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_populate_customer_id()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var specimenContext = new SpecimenContext(fixture);
        var customer = (Customer)specimenContext.Resolve(typeof(Customer));
        Assert.NotNull(customer.Id);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_populate_customer_id_with_ContractType_customization_using_with()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.Customize<ContractType>(composer => composer
            .With(x => x.Id, "FM")
            .With(x => x.Description, "Full Maintenance")
            );

        var specimenContext = new SpecimenContext(fixture);
        var customer = (Customer)specimenContext.Resolve(typeof(Customer));

        Assert.NotNull(customer.Id); // This test fails
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_populate_customer_id_with_ContractType_customization_using_do()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.Customize<ContractType>(composer => composer
            .Do(x => x.Id = "FM")
            .With(x => x.Description, "Full Maintenance")
            );

        var specimenContext = new SpecimenContext(fixture);
        var customer = (Customer)specimenContext.Resolve(typeof(Customer));
        Assert.NotNull(customer.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `Do` with `With`?

Comment: This looks like a bug: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/531